# base64 decoding a string containing emoji in java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, encoding, emoji

I am base64 decoding string, which has emojis, in Spring MVC back end with the following code.

```
    byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncodedStr);
    try {
        strToSave = new String(decoded, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
```

After saving the decoded string into MongoDB, most the decoded emojis are �s, which is the replacement character. What went wrong here?

Comment: Did you try to log after decoding ?

Comment: And you should specify how you emojis are shown ? If you're using them as pictures probably its not about decoding.

Comment: what do you mean by using as pictures? Doesn't MongoDB save characters in utf-8? It seems like they emojis are not saving in correctly.

Comment: We need an example, what do you mean by emoji ? Could you please share an example string with "emoji" in it.

Comment: "Hello❤️❤️this is a test" This string gets base64 encoded from front end. Then in the backend, I am base64 decoding it. But I'm getting "Hello���this is a test".

Comment: Okay, I've tried "Hello❤️❤️this is a test" string to encode, decode and save database via Mongoclient and all processes worked as expected, I would recommend you to save this string as encoded into your database when you get it from DB, you can decode it to give frontend.

Comment: I suspect Java string only supports \u0000 to \uffff, and that's why the emoji is not parsed correctly...

Comment: It should be about "UTF-8"

Comment: The UTF-8 charset is specified by RFC 2279; from java charset documentation. I guess this is not an implementation error...

Comment: No, on the other hand, why don't you try to save emojis directly from mongo shell, so you can be confident it's not about mongodb.

Comment: I will close this question. I was mainly concerned with the java code being wrong. I know mongo accepts utf-8, although I don't know which standard. Do you know?

Comment: Hi, I am having this issue. Did you get it resolved? found out why?

Comment: @zatef yeah, ended up compressing and decompressing the whole string.